# how to remove comma while update?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['save']))
{
    $checkbox1=$_POST['company_name'];  
    $chk="";  
    foreach($checkbox1 as $chk1)  
       {  
          $chk .= $chk1.",";  
       }  
    $sql = "update all_university set placement = '$chk' where university_name = '".$_POST['university_name']."'";
    $value = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    if($value == true)
    {
        $msg .="<h5 style='color:green'>Successfull</h5>";
    }
    else
    {
        $msg .="<h5 style='color:red'>Error!</h5>";
    }
}
```

?>

when I click on save button the data will store like a,b,c,. So, my question is how to remove last comma while storing in database i.e. (c,).

Thank You

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php

Comment: you can also use php's `implode` `explode` functions

Comment: Why don't try `trim()` function?? And also you can use the `implode()`

Comment: @Jeff You have 8 answers. Check them and mark the most suitable as "answered"

Answer (score 3):

Just trim it off before using it:

```
$chk = rtrim($chk, ",");
// $sql = "update all_u...
```

Comment: Here you go to 10k dude!

Answer (score 3):

Use an array instead. You can then implode the values with the comma:

```
$chk = array();  
    foreach($checkbox1 as $chk1){  
          $chk[] = $chk1;  
    } 
$chk = implode(",",$chk);
```

Or something like this:

```
$chk = implode(",",$checkbox1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['save']))
{
    $checkbox1=$_POST['company_name'];  
    $chk="";  
    /*foreach($checkbox1 as $chk1)  
       {  
          $chk .= $chk1.",";  
       }
*/

//use this code instead your foreach loop
$chk = implode(",",$checkbox1);  
    $sql = "update all_university set placement = '$chk' where university_name = '".$_POST['university_name']."'";
    $value = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    if($value == true)
    {
        $msg .="<h5 style='color:green'>Successfull</h5>";
    }
    else
    {
        $msg .="<h5 style='color:red'>Error!</h5>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding each value separetely you shoul use phps `implode`:

```
$chk = implode(",", $checkbox1);
```

Comment: Dude, you're missing your glue.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$chk = rtrim($chk, ",");`

Comment: Some people may not be familiar with the `rtrim` function. Please provide an explanation of how this answer works.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the updated code

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['save']))
    {
        $checkbox1=$_POST['company_name'];  
        $chk="";  
        foreach($checkbox1 as $chk1)  
           {  
              $chk .= $chk1.",";  
           }  
        $chk = substr($chk, 0,-1);
        $sql = "update all_university set placement = '$chk' where university_name = '".$_POST['university_name']."'";
        $value = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
        if($value == true)
        {
            $msg .="<h5 style='color:green'>Successfull</h5>";
        }
        else
        {
            $msg .="<h5 style='color:red'>Error!</h5>";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as it is to use the `implode()` function, No need to use the loop for the string fro array like `a,b,c`. If you think your some of your `company_name` may also blank then your `array_filter()`. Like: `$_POST['company_name'] = array_filter($_POST['company_name']);`

my concern: `$chk = implode(",", $_POST['company_name']);`

**Full example:**

```
if(isset($_POST['save'])) {
    $chk = implode(",", $_POST['company_name']);  
    $sql = "update all_university set placement = '$chk' where university_name = '".$_POST['university_name']."'";
    $value = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    if($value == true){
        $msg .="<h5 style='color:green'>Successfull</h5>";
    } else {
        $msg .="<h5 style='color:red'>Error!</h5>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clean code is

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['save']))
{        
   $chk=""; 

   if(isset($_POST['company_name']) != '') {
      $chk = implode(", ", $_POST['company_name']);
   }

   $sql = "update all_university set placement = '$chk' where  university_name = '".$_POST['university_name']."'";
   $value = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
   if($value == true)
   {
        $msg .="<h5 style='color:green'>Successfull</h5>";
    }
    else
    {
        $msg .="<h5 style='color:red'>Error!</h5>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks justbaron, just noticed right after pressed on publish. But now it's correct.

Comment: Sorry bub how can you say that? My point is not to use directly post property just check with isset.

Comment: I know the original bad code is not coming from you :) But 1. Validate/sanitize etc. user input instead of using them directly 2.Use PDO with binding 3. Separate markup from logic 4. Use dynamic dictionaries for textual content e.g.  "Error!" 4. Code object oriented!

Comment: I agree with you. There are many points one should keep in practicing to create clean (quality) code, all types of error handling etc.. If user has questioned for code improvement then we have to consider all such points.